# Angular 8 routing component in new tab

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an Angular component callreports which I would like to open in a new tab thru click of a link button from main page.
Currently it opens fine in same page but have to press back arrow on browser to navigate back.
target='_blank' works in case of window.open with URLs but can't figure out in case of Component. Please advise if there's a way to open it in new tab in Angular 8

html

```
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <button class="m-1 btn btn-link" (click)="CallReports()" type="button">
      Call Flows
    </button>
  </div>
```

component

```
  public CallReports() {
    this._router.navigate(['callreports']);
  }
```

Comment: I can't figure out what your problem is, but have you tried this._location.back(); to route back?

Comment: I want to open callreports component in new tab

Comment: its still unclear to me what "open in a new tab" means. when you press on the tab button are you wanting to route to that page? Or do you mean you want your app to open in a new browser tab?

Comment: When I click the url, I want to component to open in a new browser tab

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update your CallReports to this:

```
  public CallReports() {
     const url = this._router.serializeUrl(
     this._router.createUrlTree(['/callreports']));

      window.open('#' + url, '_blank');
  }
```

Comment: I would ideally like this solution to work. This solution is currently giving http://localhost:14480/callreports but I need http://localhost:14480/#/callreports. So I changed your code to  this._router.createUrlTree(['#/callreports']));  But this resulted in http://localhost:14480/%23/callreports. Can you think of a way to fix this?

Comment: @silverfish updated the answer. Please check if it works.

Comment: This code works as expected  const url = window.location.href+'/callreports';
window.open(url, '_blank');

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work if you simply use html link with the URL set to the routed page. Like this:

```
<a href="www.yourpage.com/#/routed-page" target='_blank'>Click here</a>
```

Comment: this solution does work, however will have to change domain(www.yourpage.com) based on environment -dev/uat/prod

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
window.open('callreports');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
const url = window.location.href+'/callreports'; 
window.open(url, '_blank');
```

Its works as expected. and the result will be httlp://localhost:14480/#/callreports.